# WPF - UI binding how to ? how come this example code doesn't work

Tags: wpf, binding

this is my xmal mainwindow :

```
<Window x:Class="HR1.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Grid>
    <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="162">
    <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding EventsCollection}" Background="AliceBlue" Height="311" >
        <ListView.View>
            <GridView>
                <GridViewColumn Header="event Date"  Width="112"/>
            </GridView>
        </ListView.View>

    </ListView>
    </StackPanel>
    <ScrollViewer>
        <StackPanel Margin="116,0,0,0" Width="284">
            <ListView Name="employeeListView"  ItemsSource="{Binding EmployeeCollection}">
                <ListView.View>
                    <GridView>

                        <GridViewColumn Header="Employee ID" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=EmployeeID}" Width="80"/>
                        <GridViewColumn Header="First Name" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=FirstName}" Width="80"/>
                        <GridViewColumn Header="Last Name" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=LastName}" Width="80"/>
                        <!--<GridViewColumn Header="start" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=startHR}" Width="67" />
                        <GridViewColumn Header="finish" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=finishHR}" Width="67"/>-->



                    </GridView>

                </ListView.View>

            </ListView>
        </StackPanel>
    </ScrollViewer>
</Grid>
```

where this is the code behind:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows; 
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using HR1.Model;

namespace HR1
{
/// <summary>
/// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
/// </summary>
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{

    private CollectionView employeeCollection;
    private CollectionView eventsCollection;

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        initlalizeEmployeeList();
        initlalizeEventDateList();
    }

    private void initlalizeEventDateList()
    {
    IList<employeeData> list = new List<employeeData>();
    //query to database should be here
    foreach (employeeData dataString in employeeDatesString)
    {
        list.Add(dataString );
    }
    employeeCollection = new CollectionView(list);
}



    private void initlalizeEmployeeList()
    {
        IList<eventDate> list = new List<eventDate>();
        //query to database should be here
        foreach (eventDate dataString in eventDataString)
        {
            list.Add(dataString);
        }
        eventsCollection = new CollectionView(list);
    }


    #region collection binding setters 
    public CollectionView EmployeeCollection
    {
    get { return employeeCollection; }
    }
    public CollectionView EventsCollection
    {
        get { return eventsCollection; }
    }
    #endregion

    #region myDatabinding
    static employeeData []employeeDatesString = {new employeeData(1234,"yoav","stern "),new employeeData(1234,"yoav","stern ") };
    static eventDate[] eventDataString = { new eventDate("111"), new eventDate("2222") };
    #endregion


}
```

}

and this the data i store in tow classes which are stored in two places:

```
 using System;
 using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.ComponentModel;

namespace HR1.Model
{
class eventDate : INotifyPropertyChanged
{

    public eventDate(string s) 
    {
        Date = s;
    } 
    #region private members
    private string date;
    #endregion

    #region proprties
    public string Date
    {
        get
        {
            return this.date;
        }
        set
        {
            date = value;
            if (value != this.date)
            {
                this.date = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("Date");
            }
        }
    }
    #endregion

    #region events
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    #endregion
    private void NotifyPropertyChanged(String info)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(info));
        }
    }

}
```

}

and this the second one :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.ComponentModel;

namespace HR1.Model
{
class employeeData : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
public employeeData(long ID,string  f,string l){
    EmployeeID = ID;
    LastName = l;
    FirstName = f;
}

#region privete Members

private long employeeID;
private string firstName;
private string lastName;

#endregion

#region proprties

public long EmployeeID
{
    get
{
return employeeID;
}
set
    {
        employeeID = value;
        if (value != this.employeeID)
        {
            this.employeeID = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("EmployeeID");
        }
     }
}

public string FirstName
{
    get
    {
        return firstName;
    }
    set
    {
        firstName = value;
        if (value != this.firstName)
        {
            this.firstName = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("FirstName");
        }
    }
}

public string LastName
{
    get
    {
        return lastName;
    }
    set
    {
        lastName = value;
        if (value != this.lastName)
        {
            this.lastName = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("LastName");
        }
    }
}

#endregion

#region events
public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
#endregion
private void NotifyPropertyChanged(String info)
{
    if (PropertyChanged != null)
    {
        PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(info));
    }
}
}

}
```

notice : in my point of view somewhere where i declared 
    EmployeeCollection 
and the xmal line:

```
<ListView Name="employeeListView"  ItemsSource="{Binding EmployeeCollection}">
```

I did wrong couse the two doesn't bind as they should have

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out what the problem is 
i nedded to do

NotifyPropertyChanged("somelist");

example :

```
   private void initlalizeEventDateList()
    {
    IList<employeeData> list = new List<employeeData>();
    //query to database should be here
    foreach (employeeData dataString in employeeDatesString)
    {
        list.Add(dataString );
    }
    employeeCollection = new CollectionView(list);
    NotifyPropertyChanged("employeeCollection");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you change that first `<Grid>` to:

```
<Grid DataContext="{Binding ElementName=window}">
```

and add `x:Name="window"` to the root Window element, then does it work?

Comment: NOPE and you r missing ": <Grid DataContext="{Binding ElementName=window}"> (if someone else would find this post helpful adding the " would be helpful for him ...)

Comment: Ok i've changed my post. Can i recommend that you try and pare your code down to the simplest possible case that demonstrates your problem?

Comment: i dont know what the proble, is i tried to bind using :
 <ListView Name="employeeListView"  ItemsSource="{Binding EmployeeCollection}">

that shoulds bind to my code variable :public CollectionView EmployeeCollection but it doesnt work ... (i gave EmployeeCollection instance value in the constructor)

Answer (score 0):

Update your MainWindow constructor to:

```
public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            initlalizeEmployeeList();
            initlalizeEventDateList();

            this.DataContext = this;
        }
```

Comment: thank you but still it does not work.... (I didn't switch to other user controls ... and it doesn't work ...)

Comment: what do you mean "it doesn't work" exactly?  There are no items appearing in the two ListViews?